# Apply JavaScript on inputs dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

I have a form:

```
<form name="test">
<input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="X">X
<input type="radio" required="required" name="a" value="2">2
<br />
<input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="b" value="2">2
</form>
```

This is my goal:

```
If a=1 then b=1
If a=X then unset b
If a=2 then b=2
```

This is how I achieve it atm:

```
$('input[name="a"]').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $('input[name="a"]:checked').val();
  if (selected == "X") {
    $('input[name="b"]:checked').prop("checked", false);
    return false;
  }
  $('input[name="b"][value="' + selected + '"]').prop("checked", true);

});
```

The question is: what if there are multiple input "pairs" in my `form` and the name is dynamically set like this:

```
<form name="test">
<?php
  foreach($arr as $item) {
  $input = '
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="'$item['id'].'a" value="1">1
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="'$item['id'].'a" value="X">X
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="'$item['id'].'a" value="2">2
    <br />
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="'$item['id'].'b" value="1">1
    <input type="radio" required="required" name="'$item['id'].'b" value="2">2
  ';
  echo($input);
}
?>
</form>
```

How can I apply the same javascript to handle all of them?

Comment: use array for this

Comment: If you want to implement it in a simpler method use classes. inputs with value 'a' will all have the same class and inputs with value 'b' will all have the same class. It'll be easy to differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47544/

I change ID 144a / 144b for this example.

HTML:

```
<form name="test">
<input type="radio" required="required" name="144a" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="144a" value="X">X
<input type="radio" required="required" name="144a" value="2">2
<br />
<input type="radio" required="required" name="144b" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="144b" value="2">2
</form>
```

js :

```
$('input').on('change', function(event) {
 if(event.target.name.slice(-1) == 'a'){
 var nameA = event.target.name;
 var nameB = event.target.name.slice(0, -1) + 'b';
  var selected = $('input[name='+nameA+']:checked').val();
  if (selected == "X") {
    $('input[name='+nameB+']:checked').prop("checked", false);
    return false;
  }
  $('input[name='+nameB+'][value="' + selected + '"]').prop("checked", true);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute selector's *ending with* `$`.

With that it won't matter what `$item['id']` will be, you'll still find them with their ending `a` or `b` and so on.

```
$('input[name$="a"]').on('change', function() {...});
```

Then, by simply grab the *id number part* using `slice()`, it gets as simple as below sample

Stack snippet

```js
$('input[name$="a"]').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this),
      val = selected.val(),
      id = selected.attr('name').slice(0,-1);
  if (val == "X") {
    $('input[name="'+id+'b"]:checked').prop("checked", false);
    return false;
  }
  $('input[name="'+id+'b"][value="' + val + '"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test">
<input type="radio" required="required" name="1a" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="1a" value="X">X
<input type="radio" required="required" name="1a" value="2">2
<br />
<input type="radio" required="required" name="1b" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="1b" value="2">2
<br /><br />
<input type="radio" required="required" name="2a" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="2a" value="X">X
<input type="radio" required="required" name="2a" value="2">2
<br />
<input type="radio" required="required" name="2b" value="1">1
<input type="radio" required="required" name="2b" value="2">2
</form>
```

Comment: If I click on my first input `1a` then this sets all the other `b` inputs, `1b`, `2b`, `3b` etc. to be `1`. While if I set `1a` I only want to set `1b`.

Comment: @fishmong3r Then simply `slice()` the id out. Will update in a sec.

Comment: @fishmong3r I updated the answer with a new, simplified version of your fiddle, that keeps the CSS selector but grab the number part from the `id` using `slice()`

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to your form, and a class to all of your inputs so that you can then set an event to all of them like this:

```
 $("#formID").on('change', '.input-class-a', function()
 {
        //stuff to do

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a common class for all checkbox and also can use itemId to unique identity radio box group.

```
<form name="test">
<?php
foreach($arr as $item) {
 $input = '
<input type="radio" class="radioBox" required="required" 
name="'$item['id'].'_a" value="1">1
<input type="radio" class="radioBox" required="required" name="'$item['id'].'_a" value="X">X
<input type="radio" class="radioBox" required="required" 
name="'$item['id'].'_a" value="2">2
<br />
<input type="radio" class="radioBox" required="required" 
 name="'$item['id'].'_b" value="1">1
<input type="radio" class="radioBox" required="required" 
name="'$item['id'].'_b" value="2">2
';
echo($input);
}
?>
</form>

$('form').on('change','.radioBox', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var ItemId=$(this).attr('name').split("_")[0];//get item id
  if (selected == "X") {
    $('input[name="'+ItemId+'_b"]:checked').prop("checked", false);//use item id for b
    return false;
  }
  $('input[name="'+ItemId+'_b"][value="' + selected + '"]').prop("checked", true);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you will always have ".a" or ".b" at the end of the name,  so you can use the ends with selector:

```
$('input[name=$".a"]').on('change', function() {
var selected = $('input[name=$".a"]:checked').val();
if (selected == "X") {
$('input[name=$".b"]:checked').prop("checked", false);
return false;
}
$('input[name=$".b"][value="' + selected + '"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```

you are now searching only the postfix of the name.

Comment: sorry, i didn't copy, just answered at the same time